# passing a glob pattern as args in vscode linux python run configuration

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, cmdline-args

in *VScode* on linux, when I need to set an argument for the *python* executable `my_scipt.py` that I am working on,
and this arg is supposed to be a glob pattern like
`some/where/like_*`,
I suspect it could be done by passing this arg in the jscript description
of the run configuration (in workspace or folder files).

so I do smth. like:

```
"configurations": [
{...
"program": "some/where/my_scipt.py",
"args": ["--glob", "some/where/like_*", ...],
...}
]
```

but this will be expanded to the list of all found glob matches on execution of the run configuration.

- quoting does not help, because then the glob pattern is not understood.
- tried: `"'lkajs/ölksafd_*'"`
- tried: `"\"lkajs/ölksafd_*\""`
- tried: `"lkajs/ölksafd_\*"`
- tried: `"lkajs/ölksafd_\\*"`

what do I miss?

Comment: I have a similar issue with [passing arguments with `cmd` in Windows](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/145265), there is not a method to describe the addition of quotes to all/certain arguments, It looks like the Powershell method is better because it puts all arguments in quotes, but not handy if you want the shell to expand wildcards, but sometimes you don't want to, maybe the number of files will exceed the command line maximum length, some people have >1000 files to process

Comment: under windows vscode, and due to different/missing glob shell expansion, this seems to work as expected with the initial syntax example.  
for linux there seems to be a bash shell injection of falsely parsed arguments on execution of the run config.

Comment: Can you use the last pattern `"lkajs/ölksafd_\\*"` and then in your `.py`, you remove double backslashes before * ?

Comment: @Philippe if I understood you correctly, this solution this makes no sense to me, since when calling the script from e.g. ipython or the shell, it should also work.  
I want consistent behavior.

Comment: I know that. What I suggested is just a workaround due to the limitation of vscode.